# How to make a model having two foreign Key relations with the different models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have made an app in which i have made three models as below:

```
from django.db import models

class Class_Mgmt(models.Model):
    class_name = models.CharField(max_length=8,null=False,blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.class_name


class Section_Mgmt(models.Model):
    stu_class=models.ForeignKey(Class_Mgmt)
    section_name=models.CharField(max_length=1,null=False,blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.section_name

class Teacher_Mgmt(models.Model):
    teacher_name=models.CharField(max_length=50,null=False,blank=False)
    tea_class=models.ForeignKey(Class_Mgmt)
    tea_section=models.ForeignKey(Section_Mgmt)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.teacher_name
```

Here, `Section_Mgmt` class has a foreignKey relation with `Class_Mgmt` that means when i run the project and add a new `section_name`, then `class_name` will be selected from a drop-down list of all the existing classes. It is working well in the project.
But, in the `Teacher_Mgmt` model, i want to do like this: When i enter a new teacher in my form, then when i select the existing class from the dropdown list, then it will only show the sections available on the selected class because, `section_Mgmt` model also has the foreign key relation with the `class_Mgmt` model.

At present, when i am running the project and enter a new teacher, and select a class from the dropdown showing all the existing classes,then is showing all the sections instead of showing only those sections available in that class.

Answer (score 0):

Django does not have this functionality built in but you can use [django-smart-selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects). Just install this library and change the Teacher_Mgmt to the following code:

```
from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedForeignKey 

class Teacher_Mgmt(models.Model):
    teacher_name=models.CharField(max_length=50,null=False,blank=False)
    tea_class=models.ForeignKey(Class_Mgmt)

    tea_section=ChainedForeignKey(
        Section_Mgmt, 
        chained_field="tea_class",
        chained_model_field="tea_class", 
        show_all=False, 
        auto_choose=True
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.teacher_name
```

Comment: No, it is not working. By doing so i am not capable of selecting the dropdown list in the section field.  This is my form.py file:  from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from AttendenceApp.models import Class_Mgmt,Section_Mgmt,Teacher_Mgmt

class ClassForm(ModelForm):
 class Meta:
  model=Class_Mgmt
  fields=['class_name']

class Section_MgmtForm(ModelForm):
 class Meta:
  model=Section_Mgmt
  fields=['stu_class','section_name']

class Teacher_MgmtForm(ModelForm):
 class Meta:
  model=Teacher_Mgmt
  fields=['teacher_name','tea_class','tea_section']